# NGINX proxy and NodeJS App : href and sytylesheets and javascripts

Tags: node.js, nginx, proxy

I have a node app the has a stylesheet,javascript and images directories in a public directory from the main node app directory.

When the index.html is rendered the HTML href calls to these directories fails,  the proxy does not know how to route them since the location is not provided in the href .

So im stumped as to whether this is a Nginx or Node issue. I can proxy to other webservers such as Tomcat that do not have this issue.

Rendered HTML:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/foundation.min.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/motion-ui.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/foundation-icons/foundation-icons.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/js-image-slider.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/generic.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
<script src="/javascripts/js-image-slider.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
```

NGINX: location

I have tried many variations on this based on blogs but find none that work.

```
    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }

    #Node App Server : latest try
    location ~ /internship  {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }

    #Tomcat server
    location  /bi {
            rewrite ^/bi(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5566;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
```

Comment: Found that i needed to remove the leading '/' from the href pathing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it might be a good idea for you to read into Nginx a bit more.
As for your problem it seems you don't have anything that handles sending any files back as a response. 
Looking at Nginx docs shows the following example for returning images:

```
location /images/ {
   try_files $uri /images/default.gif;
}
```

This example looks for the location prefix of /images/ and then it'll try to find the requested location else return a default image.
You could make a similar request with your stylesheets and js.

Take a look at the [try_files documentation here.](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files)

However, I would spend a bit more time exploring what these directives mean because you can easily open a security hole by not denying access to other parts of your website.